# Windows 10 wan't reconnect to my wifi spot after reboot

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-10, lan

I have two active adapters on my PC under Windows 10: LAN and Wi-Fi; however, 
when I connect to Wi-FI I check the option "connect automatically", but after a reboot I have lost the Wi-Fi connection to router; but when I plug out my LAN cable everything is OK.

Does anyone know what can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

See if you have any updates pending and connect pc with LAN to update. Make After updates installed reboot your pc and see if it connects.

If it is still not connecting then make sure your wifi driver is installed and updated.

If you have done everything and still no wifi then Re-install driver. Please reboot if required.

Still not working? Then your built-in wifi hardware is having issues.

Buy a USB wifi device and test that.